# What's the general approach to good questions that are buried on SE?

Tags: discussion

I find/see many great questions on SE that are dated, unanswered, or basically abandoned, and find myself wanting to ask them on JSE, but stop short thinking it's some sort of plagerism, lol.  It's not the rep I'm interested in, but getting the good knowledge to JSE, if for nobody but myself when I'm wondering about it again.

Is there some process or protocol for this - thoughts?

Comment: This is on the tail of understanding that all the old Joomla questions on SE will not be migrated in any way, so it seems like lost knowledge to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, I think you should ask them on JSE as it's now the new place with a nice tight community that provide detailed answers. As JSE becomes more popular, the Joomla tag on SO will slowly be used less and less.

Comment: With no threat of a Plagerism lawsuit, I hope, lol

Comment: I think what I'll do is post what I believe is a good question, take the Rep if it is, but leave the answer for others to post and get the Rep.  Seems fairer than taking all the rep for a question and answer that I found somewher else,lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the questions where you have genuine interest. It should be straightforward to reformulate the original question. If you already have an answer, just go ahead and post it.